# Selenium - AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'driver'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, attributeerror

I'm new in Python so after a lot of attempts I decided to ask for help first time.

I receive below error:

```
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'driver'
```

Can you help my understand what it means and why it happened?

My code is as below.

File: ChromeBrowser.py

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

def init_driver(url):
    driver.get(url)
    return driver
```

File: helpers.py

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class LogIn:

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def choose_method(self,method,locator):
        self.method = method
        self.locator = locator
        WebDriverWait(self.driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((self.method,self.locator))).click()
```

File: run.py

```
from Log_In.ChromeBrowser import *
from Log_In.constants import Constants as C
from Log_In.helpers import LogIn
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def run():

    browser = init_driver(C.url)
    LogIn.choose_method(browser, By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#credentialSignin')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

I try to run run.py file firstly. Browser is open with proper website (URL is passed from `constants.py` file) and as I understand instance of Chrome is stored in **browser** object. Then using class **LogIn** and method **choose_method** I wanted to wait for proper element of website and when it will be visibly click it.

Answer (score 0):

the problem might be in the run.py file.
Try the following:

```
def run():
    browser = init_driver(C.url)

    # Create an instance of the LogIn class
    login_page = LogIn(browser)

    # Call the choose_method method on the instance
    login_page.choose_method(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#credentialSignin')
```

In your code you're trying to call the choose_method on the class, this is not exactly how it works.
Normally, whenever you deal with Classes, for example a Dog_Class, you want to create an instance for each dog you'll have in the code. dog_1 = Dog_Class(), dog_2 = Dog_Class(), etc. At this point you can tap into every Dog_Class method and attribute just by doing dog_1.a_method(args).
Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation! It works perfectly :)
​